# Argument 1 passed to Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Http\RedirectResponse given

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm running Laravel 5.3 and try to modify my registration code to have activation mail feature as referenced in:

https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-email-verification-with-activation-code.html#.WBCTI_l946Q

but i received error:

> FatalThrowableError in SessionGuard.php line 441: Type error: Argument
>   1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement
>   interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
>   Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given

here is my create method inRegisterController:

```
protected function create(array $data){
    $user = new RestUser($data);
    $user->register();
    $this->activation->sendActivationMail($user);
    //return redirect('/login')->with('activationStatus', true);
    return redirect('/login')->with('status', 'We sent you an activation code. Check your email.');
    //return $user;
}
```

how can i overcome this?

thanks!

Comment: What is `RestUser` and what is `RegisterController`.

Comment: Rest user is my modified User model - it's rolled same like User Model, but just instead of using eloquent, i modified it to fetch from rest api instead.  

register controller is a default registration controller that come with Laravel when you 'make auth'